# Pollution of 3 lakes with differential equations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider three lakes of equal volumes connected to each other with a flow.[image: 3 lakes]

An accident results in the spillage of 300 000 kg of chemicals in Lake 1. Calculate the quantity of this chemical present, after the accident, in each of the lakes, assuming that it remains in one of the three lakes.
Then the problem gives me this suggestion:

Suggestion: construct the illustrated compartmental model in which $l_i(t)$ indicates the quantity of
pollutant in lake $i$ at time $t$, $V$ is the volume of each of the lakes and $r$ is the flow rate between 2 lakes
[image: compartment model]

and deduce the equations
\begin{align}
    \frac{dl_1(t)}{dt}&= -r\frac{l_1}{V}+r\frac{l_3}{V}\nonumber\\
    \frac{dl_2(t)}{dt}&=-r\frac{l_2}{V}+r\frac{l_1}{V}\nonumber\\
    \frac{dl_3(t)}{dt}&=-r\frac{l_3}{V}+r\frac{l_2}{V}\nonumber
\end{align}

with the initial condition $l_1 (0) = 300000$ kg, $l_2 (0) = 0$ and $l_3 (0) = 0$. Indicate how to bring these three equations to the system of two equations that need to be resolved:
\begin{align}
    \frac{dl_1(t)}{dt}&= -r\frac{l_1}{V}+r\frac{300 000-l_1-l_2}{V}\nonumber\\
    \frac{dl_2(t)}{dt}&=-r\frac{l_2}{V}+r\frac{l_1}{V}\nonumber
\end{align}

I was wondering how can I transform the 3 differential equations into the 2 differential equations above? Thank you!

Comment: Nice problem and nice job starting it off. Are you looking to see the long-term behavior of this system or are you trying to solve this analytically. If it is analytically you need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of your system. Furthermore, for simplicity, I would take natural units here so $l_1(0) = 1, l_2(0) = l_3(0) = 0$ and $r/V = 1$ to simplify the notation.

Comment: @Gregory Yes, I have to solve it analytically with the numbers given above so I unfortunately cannot simplify the problem, but I will give eigenvalues and eigenvectors a try, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Use linear algebra! Let $a = V/r \in \mathbb R$. Then we need to solve the following constant-coefficient linear system of ODE:
$$\begin{cases}
a\dot x(t) = - y(t) - z(t) \\
a\dot y(t) = - x(t) - z(t) \\
a\dot z(t) = - x(t) - y(t)
\end{cases} \iff a \dot{\mathbf x}(t)=a \begin{bmatrix} \dot x(t) \\ \dot y(t) \\ \dot z(t) \end{bmatrix} = -\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\  1 & 0 & 1\\  1 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  x(t) \\  y(t) \\  z(t) \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf A \mathbf x(t).$$
Then you should try to diagonalize the matrix $\mathbf A = \mathbf M \mathbf J \mathbf M^{-1}$, change basis/coordinates from $\mathbf x$ to $\mathbf x':=\mathbf M \mathbf x$, solve the diagonalized system, revert to the original basis, and fix the constant by imposing the initial conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I will attempt this!